# In Cython, if I don't add "except + " to c++ function declaration , and just do a try / catch on python side for RuntimeErrors, won't that work?

Tags: cython

if i declare a c++ function in a pxd file without `except +` at the end, but still do try/catch on my python calling code, except i catch everything or just catch 'RuntimeError', won't that have same effect as having `except +` ? According to http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#exceptions, most of C++ exceptions will be converted to RuntimeError anyway even with except +.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that will not work.

`except +` is the indicator that tells Cython to generate the code that converts C++ exceptions to a Python exception. Without it Cython will assume that the function cannot throw a C++ exception and the C++ exception will propagate through the Cython code breaking everything.

Comment: What does 'breaking everything' mean? What will happen to my python calling code in this case?

Comment: Most likely it'll just terminate because there isn't a c++ `try/catch` above. Even if there is it'll mess up the reference counting/memory management/other logic since neither Cython nor the Python internals are designed to let c++ exceptions propagate through. It's kind of irrelevant since it's *never* the right thing to do

Comment: so why not let the except + be the default for every cython wrapper declaration for c++ functions? or, build that capability by default without needing except + annotation?

Comment: There are disadvantages to handing c++ exceptions by default: It generates extra (probably slightly slower) code to handle the exceptions - it needs to swap things in and out of temporary variables for example. Ultimately it's just an arbitrary design decision though